# Mount a block device as a regular file

Tags: mount, rsync, dd, block-device, disk-encryption

**Preamble**

Suppose I have an encrypted partition of 1TB on machine A
containing the home directories of a dozen users, let's call this
partition `sda2`.
I want to backup that partition on a remote computer B on a daily basis.
To keep it secure and simple, the backup on B must be an exact image copy
of `sda2`.

I know I can create a local image of `sda2` with the `dd` command,
and even pipe it to B through `ssh`:

```
$ dd if=/dev/sda2 | ssh B dd of=/backups/A.sda2.image
```

The problem with this approach is the sheer size of the partition.
1TB of data doesn't pass through the network easily and this puts a limit
on the frequency of backup operations---less than once in a month to be realistic. An incremental backup tool is needed at this point.

`rsync`, seems to me, is the solution to the previous difficulty. 
However I fail when I try to test it because `rsync` treats `/dev/sda2` 
as an special file and the command:

```
$ rsync /dev/sda2 B:/backups/A.sda2.image
```

doesn't do what I want.

**Question**

Is there a way to trick `rsync` to treat `/dev/sda2` a regular file?

**Note**

I'm not asking if there is an `rsync` option to do this (if there is such an option that would be great, but that's only half of the story)
I want to know if there is something like a `mount` command or system call  that would allow me to create, for instance, a regular file `/mnt/sda2.live_image` with the raw contents of `/dev/sda2`, so that
other applications can read or write directly on `sda2` through `sda2.live_image`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think writing a small file on a LUKS partition will have to change the whole 1TB. That would make such partition unpractical.

Comment: Using a device copy, if the file system is corrupt you will copy it over. With a file-based approach, if the source FS is corrupt there is still a good chance that the other end remains readable.

Comment: @Lagrange.el.Ciencia you are totally right, my comment didn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

You can patch the [passthrough_fh](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/fuse-3.9.0/example/passthrough_fh.c) libfuse demo fs like this:

```
diff --git a/example/passthrough_fh.c b/example/passthrough_fh.c
index 13eb41e..146cb03 100644
--- a/example/passthrough_fh.c
+++ b/example/passthrough_fh.c
@@ -72,6 +72,21 @@ static void *xmp_init(struct fuse_conn_info *conn,
    return NULL;
 }

+
+static void b2r(int devfd, struct stat *stbuf)
+{
+   off_t disk_size;
+
+   disk_size = lseek(devfd, 0, SEEK_END);
+   if (disk_size == -1)
+       return;
+
+   stbuf->st_size = disk_size;
+   stbuf->st_blocks = disk_size / stbuf->st_blksize;
+   stbuf->st_mode &= ~S_IFBLK;
+   stbuf->st_mode |= S_IFREG;
+}
+
 static int xmp_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf,
            struct fuse_file_info *fi)
 {
@@ -85,6 +100,16 @@ static int xmp_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf,
        res = lstat(path, stbuf);
    if (res == -1)
        return -errno;
+   if (S_ISBLK(stbuf->st_mode)) {
+       int fd;
+       if (fi)
+           fd = fi->fh;
+       else
+           fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
+       b2r(fd, stbuf);
+       if (!fi)
+           close(fd);
+   }

    return 0;
 }
```

If mount it as root, it will present you a mirror of your filesystem with block devices appearing as regular files. Pass `-omodules=subdir,subdir=/dev` to mirror only /dev.

(I'm using a variant of this patch on my dualboot Mac / Linux machine to be able to boot up my Linux installation as an Xhyve VM in OS X, as Xhyve refuses to use block devices.)

Answer (score 0):

Block device based backup are usually a wrong idea, as explained in the comment.

On a non-encrypted device, one usually would do it using the following steps:

1. Fill empty space with zero (`dd if=/dev/zero of=<mountpoint>/tmp_zero_file bs=1M`) so that free space is compressed with the better ratio.
2. Then `dd if=<your block device> |gzip -9 | ssh backup_host "cat > backup.gz"`
3. Then `rm <mountpoint>/tmp_zero_file`.

The problem here is that, since your disk is encrypted, writing 0 into a file **won't** result in zero'ed blocks because of the encryption layer.

For your use-case, i strongly recommend using [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) which is a rsync-based backup tool implementing encryption and incremental backups.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you look at the whole partition you have to read it whole to find what has changed. In fact you have to read the new version and the old version to locate the changes, so you have better bluntly copy the whole thing over. With Gigabit Ethernet and good disks, you get 100MB/s, so your terabyte is going to take 10000s or roughly 3 hours, so a nightly backup is doable. OTOH if the target is a SSD you will wear it out fast.

Note that what you do is not a backup but a mirror. It doesn't really help users who delete files by mistake if they find this out after one mirroring has happened.

Comment: Yes I have to read both to see what's changed. But in principle it is not necessary to send 1TB every night through the network. For example I could compare 10Byte-hashes of 1MB blocks and update only those blocks whose hash differ. If the disk's content didn't change at all the data transferred would be 1TB/1MB*10B=10MB, that's 0.1 seconds at 100MB/s. I guess that's what `rsync` does.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to read the whole disk and compute all these hashes, you save on the network but not on the disk I/O (which the purpose of rsync's `-B`).